# How do I switch to the non experimental version of the gradle plugin?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I see this when I go into "project structure":
[image]

I didn't realize I was using the experimental version of the gradle plugin.

How can I switch to the non-experimental version of the plugin?

Comment: Check all the versions https://services.gradle.org/distributions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open your project's build.gradle, it looks like:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0' is the key, you can change the version dependence on your android studio's version(mine is v1.5.1).

Comment: Even that version is really outdated. https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.android.tools.build.gradle/view